# "[mobx-state-tree] No matching type for union" Error

Tags: mobx-state-tree

In my dev version of my electron app, I don't get any errors. But as soon as I try to run it in production, it seems to have problem with my localStorage data. 
Any idea how to debug this?

**Stacktrace:**

```
Uncaught Error: [mobx-state-tree] No matching type for union ({ id: identifier?; date: Date?; completed: boolean?; stepResults: { id: identifier; step: ((reference((ClickStep | DragStep)) | undefined?) | undefined?); matches: { position: { x: number; y: number }; value: number; templateSize: { width: number; height: number } }[]?; frameFilePath: (string | undefined?); success: boolean?; message: (string | undefined?) }[]?; deviceData: ({ abi: string; sdk: string; osVersion: string; size: string; serial: (string | undefined?); name: (string | undefined?); brand: (string | undefined?) } | undefined?) } | undefined?)
    at We (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2715)
    at t.instantiate (mobx-state-tree.module.js:4688)
    at mobx-state-tree.module.js:4085
    at mobx-state-tree.module.js:4217
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.forAllProps (mobx-state-tree.module.js:4217)
    at t.initializeChildNodes (mobx-state-tree.module.js:4084)
    at new t (mobx-state-tree.module.js:1243)
    at xe (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2500)
    at t.instantiate (mobx-state-tree.module.js:4076)
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. I tried to load persisted data in an outdated format. Because I didn't persist data after migrating it.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your solution? Thanks!